# Intellij idea on hight dpi screen

Tags: dpi, intellij-idea, high-dpi, high-resolution

I'm using android studio on a 4k screen and my problem is all icons and fonts are small.

I fixing fonts problem by changing their size to 36 but still icons are really tiny.

I've just seen from this [link](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP) that there is a high dpi support in intellij idea since 13.1:

```
Support Windows/Linux HiDPI devices via -Dis.hidpi=true
```

I added this line -Dis.hidpi=true to studio64.vmoptions and studio.vmoptions files but nothing happen. Also there is a trick for Windows by "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" but i'm using Linux (Fedora 22). Any ideas?

Comment: As of July 28 '15 [http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/07/intellij-idea-15-eap-comes-with-true-hidpi-support-for-windows-and-linux/](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/07/intellij-idea-15-eap-comes-with-true-hidpi-support-for-windows-and-linux/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is **[known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114944#)**, fixed but not for everyone.

You need change `ANDROID_STUDIO_HOME/lib/util.jar` file to this **[patch jar](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/util.jar?file=74-227338&v=0&c=true)** for fixing icons. For more details read this [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114944#comment=27-980471). Hope it help you.

Comment: After replacing util.jar I got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader$Builder.usePersistentClasspathIndexForLocalClassDirectories()Lcom/intellij/util/lang/UrlClassLoader$Builder;
` this exception when i want to execute idea.sh

Comment: @Saeed What are your OS ?

Comment: Fedora 22 .64bit

Comment: @Saeed If you under JDK 7 and it still doesn't work. I have no idea.

Comment: I'm on JDK 8 latest version i also switch to JDK 7 and same problem appears and also switch to OpenJDK 8 & 7 and again same problem appears

Comment: @Saeed Man I have no idea. Hope JetBrains fix this issue on nearest release.